# resize or recrop gravatar

Tags: support, gravatar

I had no trouble uploading a new jpeg as my gravatar. However, it never gave me the option of choosing where to crop the image, which was a little too tall I guess. Assuming the proportions of the gravatar box are fixed, i would like to show more of the top and crop away more of the bottom.

It is possible that my computer has a way to do that to a jpeg before uploading, but so far I cannot find such a feature. I am not one to keep up with the latest in photoshop type software, as I lack a digital camera.

Comment: As a workaround, I recommend http://www.picmonkey.com/ for simple image processing such as cropping.

Comment: @user103254, thank you. I put a "museum matte" frame and enlarged the white part, then cropped that at top and bottom to approximate square. It shows as such on Main, perhaps here after a day or so.